# I am new to Apex development and trying to compile this code but failing

Tags: salesforce, apex

```java
public class InstanceTriggerHandler {
    public static void createInstanceHistoryRecord(Map<ID,Instance__c> newMap, Map<ID,Instance__c> oldMap) {
        List<Instance_History__c > listOfIntHistoryToCreate = new List<Instance_History__c >();
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields = SObjectType.Instance__c.FieldSets.Case_View.getFields();
        
        if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;
        
        for(Instance__c ins:newMap.values()) {
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember fst : trackedFields) {
                String fieldName  = fst.getFieldPath();
                String fieldLabel = fst.getLabel();
                Instance__c oldInstance = (oldMap != null) ? oldMap.get(ins.id) : new Instance__c();
    
                if (ins.get(fieldName) != oldInstance.get(fieldName)) {
                    String newValue = String.valueOf(ins.get(fieldName));
                    String oldValue = String.valueOf(oldInstance.get(fieldName));
                    
                    if (oldValue != null && oldValue.length()>255) {
                        oldValue = oldValue.substring(0,255);
                    }

                    if (newValue != null && newValue.length()>255) {
                        newValue = newValue.substring(0,255);
                    }

                    final Instance_History__c instanceHistory = new Instance_History__c();

                    instanceHistory.Field__c = fieldLabel;                                 
                    instanceHistory.Instance__c = ins.Id;        
                    instanceHistory.Field_API__c   = fieldName;
                    instanceHistory.Original_Value__c  = oldValue;
                    instanceHistory.New_Value__c  = newValue;

                    listOfIntHistoryToCreate.add(instanceHistory);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(!listOfIntHistoryToCreate.isEmpty()) {
            insert listOfIntHistoryToCreate;
        }
    }
}
```

Apex is giving me an error.

> "Invalid type: Schema.Instance_History".

I already checked my custom object and it indeed has double underscores in code everywhere it is referenced. Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you creating your own History object rather than enabling Field History Tracking and letting Salesforce do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Field history objects for custom objects need 2 underscores, try `Instance__History`. Probably easiest for you is to use http://workbench.developerforce.com/ to see all objects? You ever used "describe" operations?

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5

> Salesforce stores an object’s tracked field history in an associated
> object called StandardObjectNameHistory or CustomObjectName__History.
> For example, AccountHistory represents the history of changes to the
> values of an Account record’s fields. Similarly,
> MyCustomObject__History tracks field history for the MyCustomObject__c
> custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Schema.SObjectType.Instance__c.FieldSets.Case_View.getFields();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.